# Remove head and tail from numpy array PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray, and want to remove first h elements and last t.

As I see, the more general way is by selecting:

```
h, t = 1, 1
my_array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
middle = my_array[h:-t]
```

and the middle is [1,2,3,4]. This is correct, but when I want not to remove anything, I used h = 0 and t = 0 since I was trying to remove nothing, but this returns empty array. I know it is because of t = 0 and I also know that an if condition for this border case would solve it with my_array[h:] but I don't want this solution (my problem is a little more complex, with more dimensions, code will become ugly)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, use

```
middle = my_array[h:len(my_array)-t]
```

For completeness, here's the trial run:

```
my_array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
h,t = 0,0
middle = my_array[h:len(my_array)-t]
print(middle)

Output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This example was just for a standard array.  Since your ultimate goal is to work with numpy multidimensional arrays, this problem is actually a bit trickier.  When you say you want to remove the first `h` elements and the last `t` elements, are we guaranteed that  `h` and `t` satisfy the proper divisibility criteria so that the result will be a well-formed array?

I actually think the cleanest solution is simply to use this solution, but divide out by the appropriate factor first.  For example, in two dimensions:

```
h = 3
t = 6
a = numpy.array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])

d = numpy.prod(numpy.shape(a)[1:])
mid_a = a[int(h/3):int(len(a)-t/3)]
print(mid_a)

Output: array([[4, 5, 6]])
```

I have included the int casts in the indices because python 3 automatically promotes division to float, even when the numerator evenly divides the denominator.

Comment: You've to be careful when dealing with multidimensional arrays though. I'd prefer using `my_array.size` instead of `len(my_array)`

Comment: Good note, I will test that and edit my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `i:j` can be replaced with a `slice` object.  and `':j'` with `slice(None,j)`, etc:

```
In [55]: alist = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
In [56]: h,t=1,-1; alist[slice(h,t)]
Out[56]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [57]: h,t=None,-1; alist[slice(h,t)]
Out[57]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
In [58]: h,t=None,None; alist[slice(h,t)]
Out[58]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This works for lists and arrays.  For multidimensional arrays use a tuple of indices, which can include slice objects

```
x[i:j, k:l]
x[(slice(i,j), Ellipsis, slice(k,l))]
```